# Compile error when doing SFINAE practice

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, sfinae

I have a question about SFINAE, I met a compile error which is not expected:)
Here is my code:
sfinae.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct RouteManager
{

template <typename ROUTER, typename u = void>
struct hasMethod  : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename ROUTER>
struct hasMethod<ROUTER, decltype(&ROUTER::RouteAll, void())>  : std::true_type
{
};

void f() 
{
    f(hasMethod<ORDER_ROUTER>{});
}

void f(std::false_type)
{
    std::cout << "false type" << std::endl;
}

void f(std::true_type)
{
    order_router.RouteAll();
    std::cout << "true type" << std::endl;
}
using ORDER_ROUTER = typename T::ORDER_ROUTER;
ORDER_ROUTER order_router;
};
```

And follwoing is sfinae.cpp:

```
#include "sfinae.h"

template <typename A>
struct RouterA
{
};

template <typename DERIVED>
struct Base{};

struct TestTypes : Base<TestTypes>
{
    using ORDER_ROUTER = RouterA<TestTypes>;
};


template <typename B>
struct RouterB
{
    void RouteAll(){std::cout << "cancelAll";}
};

template class RouteManager<TestTypes> ;
int main()
{
}
```

When I compile this code, the error shows up and says " error: ‘using ORDER_ROUTER = using ORDER_ROUTER = struct RouterA {aka struct RouterA}’ has no member named ‘RouteAll’", I know this is because `template class RouteManager<TestTypes>;` but shouldn't it be sfinaed to the f(std::false_type)?

Comment: During the definition of TestTypes you start defining a type alias which is required to be used in order to create the type you want it to be an alias for.`    using ORDER_ROUTER = RouterA<TestTypes>;` - when it goes to figure out what the type of RouterA<TestTypes> is, it then has to come back and find the type of ORDER_ROUTER which it's still in the middle of trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

SFINAE only works for substituting the template argument of the **template itself**. `f` is a member of a class template and it is even not a template itself, and you are trying to substitute the template argument of its enclosing class template, so there is no SFINAE.

Moreover, informally, SFINAE only occurs in the signature, not in the definition, of a template.

With C++17, you can use `if constexpr`:

```
void f() 
{
    if constexpr (hasMethod<ORDER_ROUTER>{}) {
        order_router.RouteAll();
        std::cout << "true type" << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout << "false type" << std::endl;
}
```